# Can we do swiming and bodybuilding in the same day

Tags: bodybuilding, swimming

I have started bodybuilding and I also practice swimming,I ask if i can practice swiming in the morning and train bodybuilding in the evening..

or should i make a day for swiming and a day for bodybuilding ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does cardio on the same day as going to the gym negatively interfere with each other?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/does-cardio-on-the-same-day-as-going-to-the-gym-negatively-interfere-with-each-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do whichever one that fits your schedule. Note that if you choose to do the swimming in the morning and working out in the evening, then your nutrition needs to be looked at a bit more carefully. For example, if in the morning, after you finish your swimming workout, and you don't eat an adequate amount of carbs and protein in order to replenish your glycogen stores (basically, your energy), then your workout in the evening will suffer greatly and vice versa.

Personally, I would do them on separate days just because, bodybuilding routines require rest days. This way, instead of fully resting, you will have an active rest day which will help speed up your recovery for the next bodybuilding day. Aerobic activity has been shown to increase muscle recovery and thus this is a good option to consider. This would also be beneficial from a fat loss point of view since you would never actually be inactive. Furthermore, your nutrition could slack a little more than compared to doing both on the same day.

Assuming you work out at 100% intensity, I would personally find it taxing to do two gruelling workouts both in a day, regularly. This could potentially be taxing on the nervous system and leave you more tired overall.

So, what I'm trying to say is, you COULD do both on the same day if you pay great attention to your diet and make sure you're fueled with enough carbs and protein so you don't lose muscle and energy as well as making sure to stay hydrated. However, it would be much easier to just do them on separate days, both mentally, physically, and from a nutrition point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do both in one day. I have done (and seen many others) a body-building workout immediately followed by a swim work out many times. Just make sure you stretch and stay hydrated.